# How to add a digital hex signature to a PDF in PHP

Tags: php, digital-signature, tcpdf

I am working with GlobalSIgn digital signature using TCPDF. I send a hash of the PDF to GlobalSign and they return and hex encoded signature for the file.

TCPDF on the other hand signs documents using certificate file and private keys and they don't provide and option for using HEX encoded signatures while GlobalSign give hex signature without the private keys.

How can I add the HEX encoded signature into the PDF in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using SetaPDF (PHP Library) in order to attach a hex signature from an external web service:

https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-signer-manual/signature-modules/individual-module/

Comment: I eventually opted for setasign. It works perfectly.